# Why is my instance in the ModelForm coming through as a NoneType?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to obtain a `Profile` object within a forms.py ModelForm.

`print(type(self.instance))` will return `<class 'user_profile.models.Profile'>` as expected, but `print(self.instance)` will return an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'`

First the form:

```
class PublicToggleForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "public",
        ]

    def clean_public(self):
        public_toggle = self.cleaned_data.get("public")
        if public_toggle is True:
            print(type(self.instance))
            print(self.instance)  
        return public_toggle
```

Here is the model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True, related_name='is_profile_to')  
    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username
```

The `AUTH_USER_MODEL`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I didn't actually set the `username` field myself. I used django-allauth, and I assume they have a `username` field.

Returning the Profile object as a string representation of it's User's username hasnt given me problems before. So could it be related to the way that my form is indirectly tied to the view?
I have a FormView, and a DetailView into which the form is inserted:

This is the extent of the FormView:

```
class PublicToggleFormView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    form_class = PublicToggleForm
    success_url = '/form-success/'
    template_name = 'user_profile/profile_detail.html'
```

And the DetailView:

```
from .forms import PublicToggleForm  

class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'user_profile/profile_detail.html'  

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(
            user__username=self.request.user)
        context['public_toggle_form'] = PublicToggleForm(instance=profile)
        return context
```

Comment: What if you add `print(self.instance.user)`? Looks like profile's user field is blank.

Comment: `print(self.instance.user)` returns  `<class 'NoneType'>`  I've checked the Profile and the User in the admin. They are not empty. The profile does have a user which has a username

Comment: Try in details view fix prifile get to this: `profile = Profile.objects.get(
            user=self.request.user)`. Just remove `__username`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner it hasn't had an effect :/. But thank you for saving me a query..

Comment: Your error occures in detaliview? If you add print(profile.user) what's printed?

Comment: printing `profile.user` in the DetailView will print out the correct string rep of the object on the page. But technically I guess the error does happen in the DetailView, because the form is inserted into the DetailView using Ajax. When I ajax-submit the form from the DetailView, it will then be submitted to the `action` url of the `<form>` which is directed to the FormView. This FormView is linked to the ModelForm.  Edited the OP with more info regarding the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, when you calling `PublicToggleFormView` you don't pass current user's profile instance to the form. You can override `get_form_kwargs` method to do this:

```
class PublicToggleFormView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    form_class = PublicToggleForm
    success_url = '/form-success/'
    template_name = 'user_profile/profile_detail.html'  

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PublicToggleFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        kwargs.update({'instance': profile})
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Gotcha. Now I'm curious--what effect does passing the instance into the form through the `get_context_data` of the DetailView have? It doesn't do anything?

Comment: @Homer You have two view. `ProfileDetailView` will show details of user, and you need to pass current user instance to the form here only to show current user data. `PublicToggleFormView` update user's details and you need to pass instance here also to update correct user. So I think you need pass instance in both cases.